# downloading file from a response body

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a service that writes to the body of a GET request response. The data written could be to a PDF file, of an XLSX file.

my question is, when I make the request using the Google Chrome browser, the file is downloaded. However, when I make the same call using postman, I only get some gibberish writings in the response body (I guess the response zipped bytes) and I can't get the file to download.

Here I show my approach to download a file after I make its request to the controller:

my Ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: request_url,
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(searchCriteria),
                    success: function (response) {
                        swal("SWEET");
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        swal(JSON.stringify(err));
                    }
                });
```

in the service I set the response content and type as follows:

```
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        // Assign the byte stream's size
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());

        //Write to response stream
        Writer.write(response, baos);
```

I make the request from an Ajax call, and get the same response I got from the Postman, ***is there a way to download those bytes coming back to the Ajax ?***

Thank you.

Comment: You can't make an Ajax call that results in a file download.  If you want to cause a download then you must perform a POST (in this example)

Comment: do you mean to perform a POST using something other than Ajax ? if that so, how ?

Comment: I want to download it using an Ajax call from inside my application. I send some other data with the request so I use a POST request, this request returns a response which has the bytes of the wanted file.

Comment: Create a form element, populate the data (search criteria) and submit it.  Ajax is commonly used to avoid forms, but comes with downsides, such as not being able to trigger downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, when I made the request from the Google chrome the request was a GET request that is directed to a different controller. On the other hand, the one made with Postman is a POST request  directed to a different controller.

Contents of GET requests response can be downloaded as a file, given it's mentioned in the response header.

Contents of POST however, doesn't. I believe because POSTs are not meant to trigger any downloads as mentioned in the comments by Archer.